# france map in R (open street map)

Tags: r, maps, openstreetmap, latitude-longitude

basically im trying to create map of france with dots of citys that i have in my data base so for that ineed latitude et longtitude to create it . i couldn't use API GOOGLE it's not free so i am using now open street map to put for every city in my data base the latitude et longtitude.

but i just gor errors :
(Error in UseMethod("st_coordinates") :
no applicable method for 'st_coordinates' applied to an object of class "c('matrix', 'array', 'list')")

in general i need to create france map with dots of every city i have in my data base

Comment: Welcome to  SO! Please edit your question to include the code you added as comment.

Comment: Besides, wouldn't it be easier to use some offline dataset, like the ones provided by 
 https://www.geonames.org/ ? Or official administrative divisions? Geonames also collects data sources by country - https://www.geonames.org/countries/FR/france.html

Comment: thank you @margusl it was really helpful did get all info about latitude and longitude from "https://adresse.data.gouv.fr"

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.